# A Latin adjective for New York?

Tags: adjective, derivation, place-names

The city of New York is often called *Novum Eboracum* in Latin.
Let us ignore other options for the purpose of this question; I just want to understand city names with two or more words through an example.

Many city names have associated adjectives: *Roma > Romanus, Carthago > Carthaginiensis*, and so on.
**What would the adjective for New York, *Novum Eboracum*, be?**
I want New York to be distinct from York, *Eboracum*, if at all possible, so a plain *Eboracensis* is not great if there are options.

The adjective can probably be used as a demonym (a noun for "a person living in New York") or a general adjective (for expressing one's love of New York style pizza).
With cities this is often the case in my experience.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Catholic Church seems to use (say, *Archiepiscopus*) ***Neo-Eboracensis*** very
consistently. See, for example: [here](http://www.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_const_19651118_dei-verbum_lt.html) for 'FRANCISCUS titulo Ss. Ioannis et Pauli Presbyter Cardinalis SPELLMAN, Archiepiscopus Neo-Eboracensis.'

As they use Latin as an official language, that's probably the most official you ever get!

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a great first answer!

Comment: Isn’t *neo-* derived from Greek? Seems a strange choice...

Comment: @KRyan It is Greek, but Greek uses compound words (or prefixes like *neo-*) much more freely than Latin. Therefore a Greek version makes connecting the two words into one more natural. A somewhat similar city name familiar to the Romans is *Neapolis*, "new city".

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Nice, good to know.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta There is a difference, though. Neapolis is just the Greek name of the city transliterated into Latin; meanwhile, Neo-Eboracensis is a newly coined word. This is not how the ancients would have said it, even if the Church approves.

Answer (score 17):

Just a few days ago I was looking up the scientific name of the [Northern Waterthrush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_waterthrush): the *Parkesia noveboracensis*.

The name occurs in several other names. However, I haven't found an example of it being used in actual Latin text, so an attested form (like the above *Neo-eboracensis*) is probably preferable.

Comment: Scientists have a lot f freedom to name species, so I’ve seen both *noveboracensis* and *novaeboracensis*.

Comment: @Davislor Definitely good to note that. To judge by Google hits, though, *novaeboracensis* is considerably less common.

Comment: @Davislor novaeboracensis is most certainly ill-formed - the stem-final short /a/ is deleted in compounds without exception, and the result spells an entirely different sound, namely the dipthong /ae/, from a city of *Novum Aeboracum.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian i guess you could at least add a dieresis, so the reader would know that *Camponotus novaëboracensis* is not dipthongized into *novæboracensis*.

Comment: @Davislor that would still make it be formed from some such place as Novum Aëboracum

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian Nevertheless, that is the name of the species.

Comment: @Davislor I suspect that the "freedom" you mentioned in your first comment explains the name better than any standard of correctness--especially since that is a rare variant.

Comment: @brianpck Are you insinuating that *Ytu brutus*. *Aha ha*, *Pieza kake*, *Ba humbugi*, *Heerz lukenatcha* and *Pison eu* are not correct Latin?

Answer (score 6):

The ancient city of *Comum* (modern *Como*) was destroyed and re-built, at which point it was often called *Novum Comum* or *Novocomum* for short. The adjective *Novocomensis* is attested.

If I wanted to use *Comum* as my pattern, I would take a cue from the elision of noun endings in Latin poetry (not to mention from dbmag9 above) and shorten *Novum Eboracum* to *Noveboracum*, and use the adjective *Noveboracensis*.

Comment: *Novocomensis* is a great find!

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

How about *Novieboracensis* or *Noviboracensis*? I have no idea how bipartite city names are handled classically, though.

Comment: I feel like the initial vowel of *Eboracensis* would take precedence over the final vowel of *novum*, giving *Noveboracensis*, but I don't have any examples to base that instinct on.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the normal way to use awkward names of cities attributively is by simply using the genitive, so *Novi Eboraci*. Trying to force things into single words is usually not very Latin, despite various exceptions. There is rarely a real need for an adjective: they are usually mere conveniences.

Comment: Excellent point! The adjective *novum* is particularly prefixable, but that will certainly not be the case with all adjectives that can come as parts of geographic names. The genitive is an easy and safe bet.