# Novo v. Novus v. Novum for demonym

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, adjective, history

What would be the correct or most appropriate demonym for someone who was from New Spain? I have seen “Nova Hispania” used for New Spain in some 17century maps but wikipedia also uses “Viceregnum Novae Hispaniae” for “viceroyalty of New Spain”. I guessed maybe “Novo Hispanus” or “Novus Hispanus”? “Novum Hispanus”? None of the above? Would really appreciate the help for this conundrum.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

This prior question is relevant: [A Latin adjective for New York?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/16043/9)

You could make a compound adjective *Novohispaniensis/hispanus/hispanicus* (compare *Novocomensis*). "[Novohispano](https://dle.rae.es/novohispano)" has been used in Spanish, which if borrowed into Latin would give us *Novohispanus.* In this context, the terminal -o- of Novo- is presumably the linking vowel -ŏ-, borrowed from Greek.

Here's an example of "[Novohispaniensem](https://books.google.com/books?id=uNQEByYm2MUC&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7) picturam" from Google Books, although I'm not sure of the context.

Another option would be *Neo-Hispaniensis/Hispanus/Hispanicus* (with *neo-* from Greek *νεο-*).

"Novihispanicus" has been used as a species name, but biological Latin doesn't count for much.

*Novae Hispaniae,* the genitive of Nova Hispania, is certainly useable in many contexts.

The difference between *Hispanus* and *Hispaniensis* is said to be that *Hispanus* refers to a native whereas *Hispaniensis* refers to a non-native inhabitant of Spain. It's not clear to me how this distinction would transfer to the context of New Spain.

Comment: Add to that you could also just be *Hispanus Hispaniae Novae*, much like a Greek from Magna Graeca is still a Greek.